# Can a website tell the browser that it needs to stay awake?

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io, webrtc

I am developing a WebRTC application.
On smart phones, the screen goes dark to save energy after some time of inactivity.
This causes the socket connection to go idle, and my WebRTC connection doesn't work anymore.

While the video chat is active, all works fine, but I use WebRTC not only for video chat, so the video chat is not always active.

Some pages (for example YouTube) do not allow the smart phone to get into sleep mode.

Is there a way in my html page to tell the smart phone that it should not go into sleep mode?

Thank you!

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Wake_Lock_API

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Wake_Lock_API   Currently Chrome & Edge have this feature, but Firefox doesn't yet.   Or more importantly IOS doesn't have it yet, and with it been Apple not likely to happen any time soon,  web push notification anyone.. :)